# Is there a good acl library which supports mysql as backend?

Tags: node.js, acl

I have a system built by someone else who has used mysql as backend with nodejs. I have to implement some basic acl for it. Is there a good library which supports mysql out of box. I saw [acl-knex](https://www.npmjs.org/package/acl-knex) but it currently only supports postgres.

Comment: Spring security in (almost) database agnostic and can easily be configured. But this question is rather of topic here :-( - It is server side, and you can use either URL security or more probably for ACL method security preferently in service layer.